# what is the '0' meaning in rpm conditional macros

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

When reading some rpmbuild spec files, I come across some of the conditional macros which puzzle me.

- example1

  ```
  %if 0%{?rhel} > 7
    blah blah
  %endif

  # I understand the above block tries to check if the
  # red hat enterprise linux version is above 7, then blah blah
  # But what is the usage of the '0'?
  ```
- example 2

  ```
  %if 0%{!?pkg_name:1}
    %define pkg_name foo
  %endif

  # I understand the above block tries to check if the pkg_name
  # is not defined, then define it with the value foo.
  # But what is the usage of the '0'?
  ```

My guess is that '0' indicates the next expression to be either 'nil' or a number so that rpm would consider them as a number (such as 06, 0, or 01 in above examples) instead of a string or empty string. But I am not sure about it.

Unfortunatly, most of the online tutorial materials did not cover this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it right; it's a safeguard. The `%{?rhel}` says "replace with the `rhel` macro *if it exists* and it is OK if it does not (the `?`)."

So, if `rpmbuild` replaced it with nothing, the resulting `if > 7` would barf.